# Recently developed Lightning component not getting pulled in to my local source

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I have initialized a new scratch org and then created a lightning component in the scratch org using developer console. This is a simple component just to test the pull request. I can see that my lightning component is available when I check it via Lightning Components. The Devhub is enabled and scratch org is also properly authenticated. But when I try to pull my component to the local project which i have created using CLI it gives the following message.

> === Pulled Source No results found

But when after adding custom object or modify an existing object and then executing the pull will download my lightning component also. Why is this behavior?

Comment: you mentioned creating it using developer console? Did you create an [aura component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_create) or a [lightning web component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components)? You [can't create a LWC](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TzBNQA0) in the developer console

Comment: Have you modified / added anything to your .forceignore that could be causing the changes to be ignored?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves it a lightning component not LWC

Comment: @SergioAlcocer No. I have checked those files as well.